# My Php Validation doesn't work when inside FB Canvas iframe

Tags: php, facebook, validation

I have server side php validation for a form. When I put this form in the canvas iframe and it stopped working correctly.

`if (is_array($this->post('variable')))`

The code above is an if statement and even if the parameters are true it still goes to `else if`.
Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: can you issue a `print_r` to indicate the value of `$this->post('variable')`

Comment: The only way this could fail is if the form field ISN'T an array. PHP won't just magically decide to treat it as false, unless it really does evaluate out to false.

Comment: I highly doubt you're POSTing an array, unless the class thats putting it into $this->post is doing some reconstruction.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the first iframe run will get post variables from the Facebook. You may not expect the post vars before the form is created.